# convert command from curl to powershell

Tags: powershell, ssl, curl

I want to convert the below curl command to powershell

```
curl https://someurl.com --cacert ca.pem --cert pub.pem --key priv.pem -vvvv
```

I've worked out most of the command I need to use please see below

```
$cert = Get-ChildItem Cert:\LocalMachine\my | Where-Object {$_.DnsNameList -like 'somedomain.com'}

$url = 'https://somedomain.com'

[System.Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [System.Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12;
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -Certificate $cert -Verbose
```

However I received the below error message when I ran the script:

> Invoke-WebRequest : The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS
>   secure channel.

Comment: That issue is because of the TLS version i believe. Change it to Tls instead of tls12

Comment: tls1.0 is enabled by default in powershell 5. Also I need it to work over tls 1.2